# How can I fill a variable Char from right to left?

Tags: c, arrays, right-to-left

Usually TPV's are manufactured with integrated software and you develop the interactions between it and a Server. Now my job is to make that base development, in other words, I develop the whole thing.

My problem is the next one:

I've programmed a key in the TPV that initialices a sale. This prints a tag "Type the Price" and a `char` named "price" that is initialized as "00,00€"

That is simple. Now I would like to fill that price char from right to left, ie.:

- Pressing "1": would make the price to: 00,01€
- Next number("2"): 00,12€
- Next("3"): 01,23€
- (...): 123,45€
- (...): 123456,78€
- etc...

This price char is used with dynamic memory using functions like `calloc` and `realloc` that reserves memory for each new key pressed.

This is the code so far, for the moment i just want to implement that functionality.

```
char * precio = "00,00€";
int j;

while(1){      //Loop that waits for the sale to be initialized
    UpdateStatusbar(fontClock);
    if (!XuiHasKey()) {
            continue;
    }
    key = XuiGetKey();
    if (key == XUI_KEYUP) {
        j = sizeof(precio) - 2;

        //Position of the last element of precio (-2) to avoid the characters '\0' and '€'

        precio = (char *) calloc(4, sizeof(char));
        precio = (char *) realloc(precio, sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0'));

        (Irrelevant code for printing the: "Type the price")
        while (key != XUI_KEYENTER && key != XUI_KEYCANCEL) {

                UpdateStatusbar(fontClock);
                if (!XuiHasKey()) {
                    continue;
                }
                key = XuiGetKey();

                if (key == XUI_KEYCLEAR) {
                    if (j > 0) {
                        j--;
                        precio[j] = '\0';
                    }
                } //Function to delete as the backspace in your keyboard

                else if (key != 'e') {
                    if(strcmp(precio, "0000") == 0){
                        precio[j] = KeyToChar(key);
                    }else {
                        for (int i = 1; i < j; ++i) {
                            precio[i-1] = precio[i];
                            precio[j] = KeyToChar(key);
                        }
                    }
//This key !='e' comes for the function KeyToChar(). 'e' means Key is not a number  

                }
                precio = (char *) realloc(precio,
                        (j + 1) * sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0'));

                XuiCanvasDrawText(XuiRootCanvas(), 10, 180, 20, font,
                        XUI_TEXT_NORMAL, colorMsgFg, precio);

        } //End While
     } //End if for precio  
}//End While
```

As you can see I use some special libraries (XUI) provided by the manufacturer of the TPV

If there's needed more information ask for it and i will give it back

Comment: I would maintain an `int` instead of a `char*`, which you multiply by 10 at each key press and then add the number you pressed. Then when you need to display it you divide it by 100 and convert it to a `char*`. Seems easier to handle.

Comment: `sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0')` is `sizeof(char) + sizeof(int)`. And since `sizeof(char)` is specified to always be equal to `1`, and the size of an `int` usually being `4`, then you have `1 + 4` which equals `5`. You only allocate five bytes. Always.

Comment: What is the problem with the current code?

Comment: I forgot to say that: I know that the coma character (',') is also going to be moved like that. But i don't really know to keep that position "locked".

Comment: What is wrong with just `printf("%02d,%02d€", number / 100, number % 100);` ?

Comment: Store the result in cents and add the decimal point/comma for humans. When typed, remember (and shift) its position. You can then also ensure it isn't entered twice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude you are right i forgot to make a 'j++' for each key i press, so `precio = (char *) realloc(precio, (j + 1) * sizeof(char) + sizeof('\0'));` works propperly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and a char named "price" that is initialized as "00,00€"
>
> Pressing "1": would make the price to: 00,01€

Just use an integer and convert it to a string on each new character inputted.

I have written the below code in like 15 minutes, didn't run it. Bugs and typos are expected. I used `unsigned long long` to allow at least 9,223,372,036,854,775,806 cents to be inputted. I used `snprintf` to calculate the number of characters needed, then allocate the memory with malloc and then output the string again with `snprintf`. I assumed the `€` character is not anything special and is properly handled by your compiler/environment.

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Get's the price as a string.
 * @param the state variable that get's updated with each number
 * @param Should be the newly inputted character or 0 on clear
 *        TODO: refactor to 2 functions
 * @return an allocated pointer or NULL on error
 *         TODO: pass a pointer to that pointer and use realloc to save free call
 *           or preferably just allocate a buffer big enough on stack 
 *           like `char buf[log10(ULLONG_MAX) + sizeof(",€")]`, which shouldn't be that big actually
 */
char *price_update(unsigned long long *state, int new_char) {
   if (new_char == 0) {
      *state = 0;
   } else {
      if (!('0' <= new_char && new_char <= '9')) goto ERROR_EINVAL;
      if (ULLONG_MAX / 10 > *state)  goto ERROR_OVERFLOW;
      *state *= 10;
      const int to_add = new_char - '0';
      if (ULLONG_MAX - to_add > *state) goto ERROR_OVERFLOW;
      *state += to_add;
   }
   const int count = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%02lld,%02lld€", *state / 100, *state % 100);
   char *price = malloc(count + 1);
   if (price == NULL) goto ERROR_MALLOC;
   snprintf(price, count + 1, "%02lld,%02lld€", *state / 100, *state % 100);
   return price;
// TODO: implement your favorite solution to error handling
ERROR_OVERFLOW:
ERROR_EINVAL:
ERROR_MALLOC:
    return NULL;
}

/**
 * Clears the price
 */
char *price_clear(unsigned long long *state) {
    return price_get(state, 0);
}

// usage
unsigned long long state = 0;
int main(){
 while (1) {
     some_unrelated_code();
     int key = XuiGetKey();
     char *price = key == KEY_CLEAR ? price_clear(&state) : price_get(&state, key);
     if (price == NULL) { /* handle error */ abort(); }
     do_something_with_price(price);
     free(price); 
  }
}
```